# Resource id 5 error in sql

Tags: php, sql

Result is returning a resource id 5 error not sure what for but i am new too this

The main issue is that my if statement is not working and i thought that was due to my result

```
$query = "select * from logindetails where online='1'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
echo $result;

if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 1) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo $row['online'] . $row['username'] . $row['password'] . $row['emailaddress'] . $row['familyname'] . $row['givenname'];
    }
} else {
}

mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: What do you expect `echo $result` to give? Are you sure it's an "error"?

Comment: The main issue is that my if statement is not working and i thought that was due to my result

Comment: add a little debugging: `echo mysql_num_rows($result)`;

Answer (score 0):

It's not *really* an error. The problem is `echo $result;` - You can't just print that. It doesn't know what you want to print. Also, I suggest using `mysqli`.

Answer (score 0):

You're not really getting an error.  What you're seeing is a numeric resource identifier for an external resource which in this case, is a resource in the database.  Probably what you're looking for is [mysql_num_rows()](http://www.php.net/mysql_num_rows) which will tell you the number of rows returned.  You'll notice by following that link that the mysql* functions are deprecated and it's recommended that you use mysqli or PDO.

Answer (score 0):

The above code outputs resource id 5 because you have given echo in the 3 line,which means your query is valid ,and the code is correct,Try giving echo mysql_num_rows($result)

Answer (score -1):

Instead of `echo $result`, use `echo $result->Row;` The $result itself is an object. You want to access the Row attribute of that object.

Your if statement is only going to work if only one user is online, also. If there are more than one users online, then you are going to have more than one row, so your if statement breaks.

Try

```
foreach ($result as $row) {
    echo $row['online'] . $row['username'] . $row['password'] . $row['emailaddress'] . $row['familyname'] . $row['givenname']. "\n";
 }
```

Comment: Will you please let me know why you downvoted my answer? I'd love to do better next time!